# Prove that no three of the six angles trisectors meet at one point

Tags: triangles

I.e., that there are 12 distinct intersection points of the angle trisectors.
$ABC$ is a triangle:
[image]

with its 6 angle trisectors. Prove that $M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X$ (the trisector's intersections) are all distinct.
The only formula I found about angle trisectors is Morley's Formula, saying that $PQU$ is equilateral.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question

Comment: Beyond Morley, interesting things [there](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/Morley/Morley.shtml) using in particular **isogonal transform**.

Comment: Should be easy to check each possible configurations of Ceva, as the answer below provided. But that should take some time. General reformulation is the claim there is no combination of $x,y,z\in\{\pm 1\}$ such that:
$$(2\cos\alpha)^x (2\cos\beta)^y (2\cos\gamma )^z = 1.$$

I suppose out of $2^3= 8$ combinations, only $4$ suffice to check due to symmetry.

Answer (score 6):

Denote $\angle BAC = 3 \alpha$, $\angle CBA = 3\beta$ and $\angle ACB = 3\gamma$ and assume that $\alpha>\gamma$. If $BR$ passes through $M$ then by trig Ceva we have
$$\frac{\sin 2\alpha}{\sin \alpha}\cdot \frac{\sin \beta}{\sin 2\beta} \cdot \frac{\sin 2\gamma}{\sin \gamma} = 1.$$
Using $\sin 2\xi = 2\sin \xi \cos \xi$ we get
$$2\cos \alpha \cos \gamma = \cos \beta.$$
Since $\cos \frac \pi 3 = \frac 12$, we have
$$2\cos \alpha \cos \gamma = 2\cos \beta \cos \frac \pi 3.$$
By $2\cos \xi \cos \zeta = \cos (\xi+\zeta) + \cos(\xi-\zeta)$ we obtain
$$\cos(\alpha+\gamma) + \cos (\alpha - \gamma) = \cos(\beta+\frac\pi3) + \cos(\beta-\frac\pi3).$$
Since $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac \pi 3$, $\cos (\alpha+\gamma)$ and $\cos(\beta-\frac \pi 3)$ cancel out which leads to
$$\cos(\alpha-\gamma) = \cos(\beta+\frac\pi 3).$$
Since $\cos$ is injective on $[0,\pi]$, this means that $\alpha-\gamma = \beta+\frac \pi 3$, which is absurd: $\alpha-\gamma < \alpha < \frac \pi 3 < \beta+\frac \pi 3$.

You can prove in similar fashion that no other three lines concur.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer : Not a direct answer but a methodology.

As your question can be understood as "how can I attack such an issue ?", I would like here to propose two combined tools for such questions involving angle bisectors in a triangle : [**trilinear coordinates**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates) $(u:v:w)$ (abbreviation here : t.c.)  and their use with [**isogonal conjugation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_conjugate#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20the%20isogonal%20conjugate,the%20isogonal%20conjugate%20of%20P.) $(u:v:w) \leftrightarrow (\tfrac{1}{u}:\tfrac{1}{v}:\tfrac{1}{w})$.

I will show it through a configuration of 8 points (see figures 1 and 2) *sharing some points with your own configuration*.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : A case where the angles aren't trisected in 3 equal values (not a "Morley configuration").*

[image]

*Fig. 2 : A Morley configuration for a general triangle.*

This configuration is determined by a single point with t.c. $(u:v:w)$ in the following way (see the correspondence with Fig. 1 (and your own figure) :

$$\begin{cases}
(u:v:w)&\text{red disk}\\
(\tfrac{1}{u}:v:w)&\text{blue star ; your point O}\\
(u:\tfrac{1}{v}:w)&\text{green disk ; your point S}\\
(u:v:\tfrac{1}{w})&\text{yellow disk}\\
(u:\tfrac{1}{v}:\tfrac{1}{w})&\text{blue disk ; your point U}\\
(\tfrac{1}{u}:v:\tfrac{1}{w})&\text{green star ; your point Q}\\
(\tfrac{1}{u}:\tfrac{1}{v}:w)&\text{yellow star ; your point P}\\
(\tfrac{1}{u}:\tfrac{1}{v}:\tfrac{1}{w})&\text{red star}
\end{cases}$$

where two points with the same color are isogonal conjugates ; for example the yellow disk is conjugated with the yellow star  (their t.c. are  inverted componentwise).

**Remarks :**

1. This (2D!) points configuration can be considered as the perspective view of a cube represented with its 3 families of parallel edges prolongated until they meet resp. in $A,B,C$, playing the rôle of points at infinity.
2. The (extended) Morley configuration and its description in terms of t. c. can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_trisector_theorem).

Matlab program :

```
 function main;
    close all;
    set(gcf,'color','w');axis off;hold on;
    A=3*i+1;B=0;C=5;plot([A,B,C,A],'k');hold on;axis equal
    a=abs(B-C);b=abs(C-A);c=abs(A-B);
    cA=2*cos(aA/3);cB=2*cos(aB/3);cC=2*cos(aC/3);
    % u=0.7;v=0.8;w=0.9
    % For a Morley configuration :
    u=sqrt(cA/(cB*cC));
    v=sqrt(cB/(cC*cA));
    w=sqrt(cC/(cA*cB));

    z=T2C(u,v,w,'or');plot([z,A,z,B,z,C],'c');
    z=T2C(1/u,v,w,'pb');plot([B,z,C],'c');
    z=T2C(u,1/v,w,'og');plot([C,z,A],'c');
    z=T2C(u,v,1/w,'oy');plot([A,z,B],'c');
    z=T2C(u,1/v,1/w,'ob');plot([z,A],'c')
    z=T2C(1/u,v,1/w,'pg');plot([z,B],'c')
    z=T2C(1/u,1/v,w,'py');plot([z,C],'c')
    z=T2C(1/u,1/v,1/w,'pr');

    % Sanity check : classical Morley triangle 
    z=T2C(1,cA,cB,'*k');hold on
    z=T2C(cC,1,cA,'*k');hold on
    z=T2C(cB,cA,1,'*k')
    
 function z=T2C(ta,tb,tc,g); % Trilinear to Cartesian coord.
    global A B C a b c;
    den=a*ta+b*tb+c*tc;
    k1=a*ta/den;k2=b*tb/den;
    z=C+k1*(A-C)+k2*(B-C);g2=g(2);
    plot(z,g,'MarkerSize',10,'MarkerFaceColor',g2);hold on;
```

Comment: A very deep [document](https://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvYi8wL2ZhMDU4NzdmZjhmZWE5NmNjYzZmMWM4MDkzZWNjZGJhZTM3M2Q2&rn=SXNvZ29uYWwucGRm) by Darij Grinberg about isogonal conjugation *but without any reference to  trilinear coordinates*...